# In Textmate, how do I change the color for text inside HTML tags?

Tags: textmate

In Textmate, I'd like to change the color of text inside HTML tags. I'd prefer it if I could specify which tags would have its text color changed; I really only want text inside `<A>` tags to have a different color, but I'd also like to be able to add more tags later on if I want to.

So essentially, any code inside `<A>` tags I'd like to appear as a different color from the color used for plain text. Anyone know how I could do this? Would I have to modify the HTML bundle's Language code to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give HTML tags different colors in your TextMate.

- Open the Preferences ( Command + , )
- Click on the Fonts and Colours tab
- Create a new theme if you may OR
- For the selected theme, change the settings for the `Markup tag` element.

Comment: I don't want to change the color; I want to colorize code inside `<A>` tags, so that they are a different color from plain text.